# In micosoft online ws-federation protocol, what are the `ests` parameters and what do they do?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, adfs

I am doing ADFS authentication to SharePoint Online using Microsoft online's WS-Federation protocol.

One really confusing part of the process is the "wasignin" operation for WS-Federation protocol which is an HTTP Form Post to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf.

It is confusing because of the parameters encoded within the `wctx` parameter.

The `wctx` is an encoded string of form parameters. And the parameters are internal to the implementation of WS-Federation in this case microsoft. Microsoft's wctx seems to contain two params:

`estsredirect` = some integer. I.e. `2`

`estsrequest` = some base64 encoded string

But what do they do? They are not documented anywhere that I can find.

See https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/11/02/adfs-deep-dive-comparing-ws-fed-saml-and-oauth/ for more info about WS-Federation during ADFS handshakes.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.createsigninrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Previously opened this on https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180629/during-microsoft-ws-federation-protocol-help-describe-the-parameters-given-to-t but was told to re-open it here as it is not really a security question, more of a Microsoft implementation question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stores the context of the federation.

There is a cmdlet:

*Set AdfsWebConfig -ContextCookieEnabled*

that stores this as a cookie to persist this and adds it to the string.

e.g. imagine a scenario:

Application --> ADFS --> some other IDP

The other IDP needs to make a decision based on which application made the call. This is what is stored in the context. It is passed along the chain.

Comment: IDP stands for "Identity Provider" for anyone who didn't know the acronym like me

Comment: Can you elaborate on the base64 format? What kind of context information does one need for ADFS with sharepoint online?